# Testing a PreferenceActivity with Robolectric

Tags: android, junit, robolectric, preferenceactivity

Is it possible to test a `PreferenceActivity` with Robolectric?   Is there a getting-started guide somewhere?

I have

```
public class myPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity { ... }
```

which shows a `PreferenceFragment` containing a number of `Preference`s.  I would like to set values in some of these and verify that they are correctly stored.  I know how to check values in `SharedPreferences`.  I don't know how to prod my `PreferenceActivity` such that it causes values to be stored.

I'm struggling to get started - I can test the activity lifecycle like any other activity, but I haven't been able to find anything useful on testing the specific `PreferenceActivity` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could test your PreferenceActivity like this

```
MyPreferenceActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyPreferenceActivity.class).create().get();

activity.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

assertNotNull(activity.findPreference("yourPreference"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's been deprecated since API 11, and it's not how my activity works - it uses a `PreferenceFragment`.